# Not able to send document via POST method to a PHP page

Tags: php, file, email, google-apps-script, post

I am using Google Apps Script to send PDF stored on my Google drive via e-mail. Unfortunatly there are limitations, like the number of email I can send, so I would like to change script to moove to a PHP page I prepared with PHPmailer to send the emails.

Here is the actual solution in Google Apps Script (the working one I want to replace):

```
//Create file based on the GoogleSpredSheet URL:
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
var pdf = docurl.getAs('application/pdf');
var finalFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);

//Send e-mail
GmailApp.sendEmail (ToUser, MailSubject, MailBody, {
from: EmailFrom,
attachments: [finalFile]
});
```

So, I created a PHP page (phpmailer.php) where we can push the emails to send via POST method using following variables:

```
//Parameters
$RecipientEmail =   $_POST['RecipientEmail'];
$RecipientLabel =   $_POST["RecipientLabel"];
$EmailSubject =   $_POST["EmailSubject"];
$AttachedFile =   $_POST["AttachedFile"];
$EmailBody =   $_POST["EmailBody"];
```

I did following HTML form to test my mailer and I confirm this is well working:

```
<form action="phpmailer.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="RecipientEmail">Email du destinataire*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="RecipientEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Adresse e-mail" required>
        </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="RecipientLabel">Nom du destinataire</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="RecipientLabel" placeholder="Nom">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="EmailSubject">Objet de l'email*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="EmailSubject" placeholder="Objet" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="AttachedFile">Pièce jointe</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="AttachedFile" placeholder="Fichier">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="EmailBody">Corps de l'email</label>
        <textarea id="story" class="form-control" name="EmailBody" placeholder="Message" rows="5" cols="33"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer l'email</button>
</form>
```

So, now I am replacing my code in Google Apps Script (the first once I shared) with following code:

```
//Create file based on the GoogleSpredSheet URL:
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
var pdf = docurl.getAs('application/pdf');
var finalFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);

//Send e-mail
var payload = {
    'RecipientEmail' : ToUser,
    'RecipientLabel' : ToUserName,
    'EmailSubject' : MailSubject,
    'EmailBody' : MailBody,
    'AttachedFile' : [finalFile]
  };
var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : payload
  };
var url = "http://XXX/phpmailer.php";
var httpRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

Unfortunatly when the email is sent, the attachement is missing.

I did a `var_dump ($AttachedFile);` from the PHP page and got a `NULL`, so it means Google Apps Script is not pushing my file

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to post the document, I found another solution: I am posting content of the document.

From Google Apps Script I extract the content of the document then I encode it with Base 64:

```js
var finalFileData = finalFile.getBlob().getBytes();
var finalFileBase64 = Utilities.base64Encode(finalFileData);
```

Now I have a string, so I can post it to my PHP script.

I just had to modify my PHP to catch this POST and decode the base 64, then recreate the file based on the content.